# ASP.NET Core (document).ready read session value

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, session-variables

I am writing an ASP.NET Core MVC 6 app.

In the controller, I am setting a session variable:

```
HttpContext.Session.SetString("PrimaryNavigation", "First");
```

I need to retrieve that value in `_Layout.cshtml`:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert('<%= Session("PrimaryNavigation")%>');
    });
</script>
```

But the alert shows

```
'<%= Session("PrimaryNavigation")%>'
```

instead of its value.

In all application using Javascript, I made it run. But it seems with jQuery and ASP.NET Core, it is different.

What I am missing?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using Razor with your MVC app?   Probably should be `alert("@Session...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below:

1.Register `IHttpContextAccessor` and `session` in Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddSession();
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
...
app.UseSession();
```

2.In _Layout.cshtml, inject `IHttpContextAccessor` implementation  and use it to get the `HttpContext` and `Session` object from that.

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http
@inject IHttpContextAccessor HttpContextAccessor
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
         alert('@HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetString("PrimaryNavigation")');
    });
</script>
```

3.result:

[image]