# Reference to type 'IHtmlString' claims it is defined in 'System.Web', but it could not be found in .net6

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

I'm working on an ASP.NET application in Visual Studio 2022using NET 6 When i m rendering the script using " @Styles.Render("~/plugins/datetimepickerStyle") like this I am getting error " Reference to type 'IHtmlString' claims it is defined in 'System.Web', but it could not be found also i am not able to system.web  dll .

I have tried to many times to build rebuild try to install packages.

Comment: what was the exact error message? also, could you double check on the project file that you have `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc` installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In .net6 we add css like below:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

You can read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56806595/use-scripts-and-styles-in-asp-net-core-which-originates-from-microsoft-aspne) to know more.

Comment: Thanks a lot  I have one more question in my project I am unable to add sytem.web  reference could please suggest .net6 framework its support or not ?or how can use Session on view 
 @if (Session["LoginUser"] != null) getting error there if using this

Comment: @Jayaacharya If you want to use session , I suggest you try:`@HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetString("LoginUser")` , you can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73884640/asp-net-core-document-ready-read-session-value/73889807#73889807) to set  session value.